# How to force a newline unless this increases the total number of lines

Tags: line-breaking

Is it possible to force a newline in a specific position of a paragraph but only if this does not increase the total number of lines?

I tried by using `\penalty` with different values, and found that -10000 always forces the newline while -9999 does not enable the newline even if the total number of line breaks is the same.

Here is a possible test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\X[1]{
  \penalty-9999 % please break here if you need to break somewhere                     
  \textbf{(#1)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  Which number?
  \X{A} 5
  \X{B} 7
  \X{C} 4
  \X{D} 3
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not really. If \penalty-9999 does not cause a line break then the white space in the paragraph must be very rigid such that the rest of the paragraph can not be stretched/shrunk to cause a break at that spot. If it infinitely bad to break there it won't break unless you adjust the horizontal space or tolerances

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so i could add some very stretchable glue to get the result? How that is achieved? I added some sample code...

Comment: `\sloppy` makes the white space stretchy which makes breaking at the penalty far more likely) (you may also want to increase  `\linepenalty` so tex is less likely to make an extra line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\X[1]{% keep egreg happy
  \unskip % remove any space before this command, so we add our own
  \hskip 0pt plus .2\hsize % end line up to 20% short
  \penalty-50 % please break here if you need to break somewhere  
  \hskip 0pt plus -.2\hsize\relax % cancel skip if don't break
  \space  % and do normal space                
  \textbf{(#1)}% as above
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
  Which number?
  \X{A} 5
  \X{B} 7
  \X{C} 4
  \X{D} 3
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: doesn't work.  that is, it will not prevent an increase in number of lines.  to test: add three more items, and increase the width of the minipage to 5.2cm.  then `\renewcommand{\X}[1]{\textbf{(#1)}}` and reiterate the example.  with default breaking, 2 lines; with "controlled" breaking, 3 lines.